# How to apply LetsEncrypt SSL certificate to WWW domain?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, lets-encrypt, vesta

I am using a Hostinger VPS and Hestia CP. I can create LetsEncrypt SSL from the control panel which successfully applies to https://example.com.

It also works perfectly when I go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in Google Chrome, Opera, and Microsoft Edge.

However, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) gives "SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN" on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) actually redirects to https://example.com address anyway but for some reason, Firefox and IE don't redirect the website before the error.

So I am assuming that it leaves me with two options. Either use the SSL certificate for both www and non-www domains or find a solution to redirect the website before the error. Couldn't figure out which way is better and how to do them tho.

Comment: It's impossible to redirect the website _before_ the (browser) warning. (That would defeat the purpose of the SSL cert.) You _need_ an SSL cert that covers both www and non-www domains. FF and IE are probably upgrading the request before sending it to your server - this is likely the way all browsers will go eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new domain, it is important to also add www. subdomain to alias column. So, f.e. like on the screenshot bellow.

[image]

The next what you will do is (re)generating SSL. Now, when you generate it after the entering the alias(es), the SSL cert. will be generated also with them.

[image]

Comment: I've already done this. However, you and I were both right since I just had to wait for the machine to run some of the cronjobs to get things working. I was just being impatient. Thanks a lot anyway!